# Why is this html photo gallery not centering?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to put a photo library on my webpage but it just won't center properly and it's driving me nuts. Any suggestions?
I've tried putting so many different things for centering in the code but nothing works :/

HTML:

```
  <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; text-align: center; width: 100%" >
    <h3 align="center" class="highlight">Photo Library</h3>
    <div align="center" class="" style="max-height:450px;max-width:800px;margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px; text-align: center">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/1.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/2.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/3.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/4.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/5.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/6.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/7.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/8.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/9.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/10.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/11.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/12.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/13.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/14.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/15.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/16.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/17.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/18.png" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/19.png" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/20.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/21.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/22.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/23.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/24.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/25.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/26.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/27.jpg" style="width:auto">
      <img class="mySlides" src="images/slideshow/28.jpg" style="width:auto">
    </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
  var myIndex = 0;
  carousel();

  function carousel() {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      myIndex++;
      if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
      x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      setTimeout(carousel, 5000);    
  }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.mySlides {
    display:none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Post all of the relevant html/css/js so that we have a [mcve].

Comment: If you are trying to get the hole content to the center you can try the `<center>` html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first set the **display** to **block**. then give the **margin** to **auto**

```
.mySlides {
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;

}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that worked perfectly! I have no idea why that was even set to none originally :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to display it as a `display: flexbox`, because you are using some `flexbox` attributes like `align-content`, `align-self`